# Help with query: Get MAX value of rows that previous row has certain value

Tags: oracle

My table TEST has three columns:

```
xID          xDATE       xVALUE
01134289    19/11/2009   1     
01134289    28/12/2009   1     
01134289    31/03/2010   0     
01134289    10/06/2010   0     
01134289    28/10/2010   0     
01134289    30/03/2012   1     
01134289    14/05/2014   1     
01134289    17/07/2014   0     
01134289    30/03/2015   1     
01134289    14/05/2015   1     
01134289    17/07/2015   0
```

I need help for a query to select the MAX xDATE of rows where xVALUE=1, but only for those rows which previous one row has xVALUE=0.

In this example, there are two rows with xValue=1 and previous rows has xValue=0:

```
xID          xDATE       xVALUE
...
01134289    28/10/2010   0     
01134289    30/03/2012   1     
...
01134289    17/07/2014   0     
01134289    30/03/2015   1
```

The query should output:

```
xID          xDATE       xVALUE
01134289    30/03/2015   1
```

Comment: Databases do not keep rows "in order".  You must define `ORDER BY` in order to identify which row is the `previous row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of LAG analytic function

```
SELECT xID, MAX(xDATE),xValue FROM
(
SELECT t.*,
       CASE
            WHEN xvalue = 1 AND LAG(xvalue) OVER(
                 PARTITION BY xid
                 ORDER BY xdate
            ) = 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END
  AS cond
FROM test t
) s WHERE s.cond = 1
GROUP BY xID,xValue
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c51140890e18cb9b60b9d0e0bd08c9d)